Why header is not included or does not apply to the specific page?
When merging the multiple word templates using OpenXML in C#, they won't include the headers or even headers are not applied to the specific page as what page template header is located.  I've spent hours and hours and haven't found any luck resolving.  It is pretty easy to merge documents without headers.
Here is the code I tried:
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing
 
public class OpenXmlMerging
{
    public void MergeTemplates(string targetFilePath, List<string> sourceFilePaths)
    {
        using (WordprocessingDocument targetDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(targetFilePath, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
        {
            // Create the main document part and add an empty document to it
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = targetDoc.AddMainDocumentPart();
            mainPart.Document = new Document(new Body());
 
            // Initialize dictionaries to store parts
            var headerParts = new Dictionary<string, byte[]>();

            foreach (var sourceFilePath in sourceFilePaths)
            {
                using (WordprocessingDocument sourceDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(sourceFilePath, false))
                {
                    CollectHeaderParts(sourceDoc.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts, headerParts);

                    // Merge document body
                    MergeDocumentBodies(targetDoc, sourceDoc);
 
                    // Insert a page break if this is not the last template
                    if (sourceFilePath != sourceFilePaths.Last())
                    {
                        //InsertPageBreak(targetDoc);
                        InsertSectionBreak(targetDoc);
                    }
 
                    
                }
            }
 
            // Add headers, images, styles, and themes to the target document
            AddHeaders(targetDoc, headerParts);

            // Update header references after all headers have been added
            // UpdateHeaderReferences(targetDoc);

        }
    }
 
    private static void CollectHeaderParts(IEnumerable<HeaderPart> headerParts, Dictionary<string, byte[]> headerDict)
    {
        foreach (var headerPart in headerParts)
        {
            string uri = headerPart.Uri.ToString();
            using (var stream = headerPart.GetStream())
            {
                headerDict[uri] = ReadStreamToByteArray(stream);
            }
        }
    }

    private static byte[] ReadStreamToByteArray(Stream stream)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
 
    private static void MergeDocumentBodies(WordprocessingDocument targetDoc, WordprocessingDocument sourceDoc)
    {
        var sourceBody = sourceDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
        var targetBody = targetDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
 
        foreach (var element in sourceBody.Elements())
        {
            targetBody.Append(element.CloneNode(true));
        }
    }

    private static void AddHeaders(WordprocessingDocument targetDoc, Dictionary<string, byte[]> headerParts)
    {
        var mainPart = targetDoc.MainDocumentPart;
 
        // Helper function to generate unique IDs
        string GenerateUniqueId(IEnumerable<string> existingIds)
        {
            int i = 1;
            while (true)
            {
                var id = $"rId{i}";
                if (!existingIds.Contains(id))
                {
                    return id;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
 
        // Get existing header part IDs
        var existingHeaderParts = mainPart.HeaderParts.ToList();
        var existingHeaderIds = existingHeaderParts.Select(hp => mainPart.GetIdOfPart(hp)).ToList();
 
        var headerPartIdMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 
        // Add header parts
        foreach (var (headerUri, headerData) in headerParts)
        {
            if (!headerPartIdMap.ContainsKey(headerUri))
            {
                var uniqueId = GenerateUniqueId(existingHeaderIds);
 
                // Add new header part
                var newHeaderPart = mainPart.AddNewPart<HeaderPart>(uniqueId);
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream(headerData))
                {
                    newHeaderPart.FeedData(stream);
                }
 
                headerPartIdMap[headerUri] = uniqueId;
                existingHeaderIds.Add(uniqueId);  // Update the list of existing IDs
            }
        }
 
        // Update header references in section properties
        foreach (var sectionProperties in mainPart.Document.Body.Elements<SectionProperties>())
        {
            foreach (var (headerUri, headerId) in headerPartIdMap)
            {
                var headerType = HeaderFooterValues.Default; // Default for all pages if not specified
 
                if (headerUri.Contains("First")) // Customize based on actual header URIs
                {
                    headerType = HeaderFooterValues.First;
                }
                else if (headerUri.Contains("Even")) // Customize based on actual header URIs
                {
                    headerType = HeaderFooterValues.Even;
                }
 
                // Ensure the header reference is added for this section
                if (!sectionProperties.Elements<HeaderReference>().Any(hr => hr.Id == headerId))
                {
                    sectionProperties.Append(new HeaderReference()
                    {
                        Type = headerType,
                        Id = headerId
                    });
                }
            }
        }
 
        // Save the changes
        mainPart.Document.Save();
    }
 
    private static void UpdateHeaderReferences(WordprocessingDocument targetDoc)
    {
        var mainPart = targetDoc.MainDocumentPart;
 
        // Map existing header parts by their ID
        var headerPartIdMap = mainPart.HeaderParts.ToDictionary(
            hp => mainPart.GetIdOfPart(hp),
            hp => hp
        );
 
        // Update header references in each section
        foreach (var sectionProperties in mainPart.Document.Body.Elements<SectionProperties>())
        {
            var headerReferences = sectionProperties.Elements<HeaderReference>().ToList();
 
            foreach (var (headerId, headerPart) in headerPartIdMap)
            {
                var headerType = HeaderFooterValues.Default; // Default for all pages if not specified
 
                if (headerPart.Uri.ToString().Contains("First")) // Customize based on actual header URIs
                {
                    headerType = HeaderFooterValues.First;
                }
                else if (headerPart.Uri.ToString().Contains("Even")) // Customize based on actual header URIs
                {
                    headerType = HeaderFooterValues.Even;
                }
 
                // Check if the header reference already exists
                if (!headerReferences.Any(hr => hr.Id == headerId))
                {
                    sectionProperties.Append(new HeaderReference()
                    {
                        Type = headerType,
                        Id = headerId
                    });
                }
            }
        }
 
        // Save the changes
        mainPart.Document.Save();
    }

    private static void InsertSectionBreak(WordprocessingDocument document)
    {
        var body = document.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
 
        // Add a new paragraph to separate sections
        var paragraph = new Paragraph(new Run(new Break() { Type = BreakValues.Page }));
        body.Append(paragraph);
 
        // Create SectionProperties to define new section properties
        var sectionProperties = new SectionProperties(
            new PageSize() { Width = 12240, Height = 15840 }, // Example page size
            new PageMargin() { Top = 1440, Bottom = 1440, Left = 1440, Right = 1440 } // Example margins
        );
 
        // Append SectionProperties to the document body
        body.Append(sectionProperties);
    }

    private static void SaveAndClose(WordprocessingDocument document)
    {
        document.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
        //document.Close(); // Ensure the document is closed
    }
}



This is a whole lot of unnecessary code for the problem, which (almost) nobody will be reading. Please provide a minimal reproducible example and also include small sample documents you want to merge and show what you get and what you expect to get.

Thank you. I just removed unnecessary code and leave Header issues.

Could you try this below code:
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

public class OpenXmlMerging
{
    public void MergeTemplates(string targetFilePath, List<string> sourceFilePaths)
    {
        using (WordprocessingDocument targetDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(targetFilePath, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
        {
            // Create the main document part and add an empty document to it
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = targetDoc.AddMainDocumentPart();
            mainPart.Document = new Document(new Body());

            // Initialize dictionaries to store parts
            var headerParts = new Dictionary<string, byte[]>();

            foreach (var sourceFilePath in sourceFilePaths)
            {
                using (WordprocessingDocument sourceDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(sourceFilePath, false))
                {
                    CollectHeaderParts(sourceDoc.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts, headerParts);

                    // Merge document body with headers
                    MergeDocumentBodies(targetDoc, sourceDoc);

                    // Insert a section break if this is not the last template
                    if (sourceFilePath != sourceFilePaths.Last())
                    {
                        InsertSectionBreak(targetDoc, sourceDoc);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Add headers to the target document
            AddHeaders(targetDoc, headerParts);
        }
    }

    private static void CollectHeaderParts(IEnumerable<HeaderPart> headerParts, Dictionary<string, byte[]> headerDict)
    {
        foreach (var headerPart in headerParts)
        {
            string uri = headerPart.Uri.ToString();
            using (var stream = headerPart.GetStream())
            {
                headerDict[uri] = ReadStreamToByteArray(stream);
            }
        }
    }

    private static byte[] ReadStreamToByteArray(Stream stream)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }

    private static void MergeDocumentBodies(WordprocessingDocument targetDoc, WordprocessingDocument sourceDoc)
    {
        var sourceBody = sourceDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
        var targetBody = targetDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

        foreach (var element in sourceBody.Elements())
        {
            targetBody.Append(element.CloneNode(true));
        }
    }

    private static void AddHeaders(WordprocessingDocument targetDoc, Dictionary<string, byte[]> headerParts)
    {
        var mainPart = targetDoc.MainDocumentPart;

        foreach (var (headerUri, headerData) in headerParts)
        {
            var newHeaderPart = mainPart.AddNewPart<HeaderPart>();
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(headerData))
            {
                newHeaderPart.FeedData(stream);
            }
        }

        // Ensure headers are properly referenced in each section
        foreach (var sectionProperties in mainPart.Document.Body.Elements<SectionProperties>())
        {
            var headerReference = sectionProperties.Elements<HeaderReference>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (headerReference == null)
            {
                // Assign default header if none is present
                var headerPart = mainPart.HeaderParts.First();
                sectionProperties.PrependChild(new HeaderReference { Id = mainPart.GetIdOfPart(headerPart), Type = HeaderFooterValues.Default });
            }
        }

        // Save the changes
        mainPart.Document.Save();
    }

    private static void InsertSectionBreak(WordprocessingDocument targetDoc, WordprocessingDocument sourceDoc)
    {
        var body = targetDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

        // Insert a section break
        var sectionProperties = new SectionProperties(sourceDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements<SectionProperties>().FirstOrDefault());
        body.AppendChild(new Paragraph(new Run(new Break() { Type = BreakValues.Page })));
        body.Append(sectionProperties.CloneNode(true));
    }
}

